# 128 bit compare and swap intrinsic

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to do 128 bit cas on a C++ union containing __int128 - do I need to align this union to use the __atomic_compare_exchange_n intrinsic from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html?

Comment: Why not do this portably with `std::atomic`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Because, under POSIX, the 128 bit CAS might be implemented [with a mutex](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80878#c4).

Answer (score 7):

It depends entirely upon your target architecture.

If you're using x86, then [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) you linked says that there is no atomic compare-and-swap for 128-bit types:

> The ‘__atomic’ builtins can be used with any integral scalar or pointer type that is 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes in length. 16-byte integral types are also allowed if ‘__int128’ (see [__int128](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html#g_t_005f_005fint128)) is supported by the architecture.

On the linked documentation for [__int128](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html#g_t_005f_005fint128), it says:

> As an extension the integer scalar type __int128 is supported for targets which have an integer mode wide enough to hold 128 bits. Simply write __int128 for a signed 128-bit integer, or unsigned __int128 for an unsigned 128-bit integer. There is no support in GCC for expressing an integer constant of type __int128 for targets with long long integer less than 128 bits wide.

x86 does not have an integer mode wide enough to hold 128 bits. Even on 64-bit x86, the long long type corresponds to a 64-bit integer, which is less than 128 bits wide. Therefore, the documentation suggests that the intrinsic is not supported for 128-bit types on x86.

That said, the x86 architecture *does* have a `cmpxchg16b` instruction, which allows an atomic compare-and-exchange on 16-byte types. I don't know if the GCC `__atomic` built-ins support emitting this instruction or not. (Unfortunately, [there are some x86 processors that do not support this instruction](https://superuser.com/questions/187254/how-prevalent-are-old-x64-processors-lacking-the-cmpxchg16b-instruction); you'll need to either know for sure that either your target processor supports it, or write code that does a run-time check and falls back to an alternative implementation if it is not supported on the current system. Early 64-bit AMD processors did not support `cmpxchg16b`, and certain steppings of the Intel Core/Core 2 processors also lacked support. It is also [not supported by Intel's Many Integrated Core (MIC) architecture](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intelr-xeon-phitm-coprocessor-february-developer-webinar-qa-responses).)

Regardless, `cmpxchg16b` *does* in fact require that its destination operand be 16-byte aligned, so any intrinsic that causes it to be emitted would foist the same requirement upon its user. Annotating with `__attribute__(( __aligned__(16)))` will accomplish this goal.

If you're using an architecture other than x86, and it natively supports scalar 128-bit integer types, then you'll have to consult its documentation to see if its compare-and-swap instruction requires alignment. It probably does, and it almost never hurts performance to align data even in cases where it is not necessary.

Comment: GCC supports `__int128` on x86_64. The note in the documentation about `long long` only means you can't write an `__int128` *literal* in your source code. The type works fine otherwise.

Comment: By "x86 architecture *does* have a `cmpxchg16b` instruction" do you mean x64? Because it doesn't exist on x86 AFAIK.